# Artemis journal directory cleanup not happen

Tags: activemq-artemis

Running Artemis since last week with average processing 400-500k
message per day. But now journal directory size is around 110G and Artemis is not able to start. I have changed the log level to trace and found following messages. The below file was created on my machine before a week ago. And till now in journal directory total 17000 file got created

```
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27588.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27592.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27593.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27588.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27577.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27593.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27578.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27577.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27579.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27578.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27580.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27579.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27603.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27580.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27605.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27603.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27606.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27605.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27607.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27606.amq has negative values
2019-07-05 03:14:34,872 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.Reclaimer] activemq-data-27608.amq can't be reclaimed because activemq-data-27607.amq has negative values
```

Comment: What does "4-5 lacs message" mean?

Comment: daily we are processing 2 million messages per day. Actually file is increasing in journal directory and size goes to journal directory is around 115 GB. Due to this artemis is not functioning properly. Also updated my comment in above query

Comment: Can you provide your `broker.xml`?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like lac (or lakh) here. As you can see, they jut cause confusion.

Comment: @JustinBertram "Lac" is Indian word for 100 000.

Comment: @JamesZ, thanks for the clarification! I've not seen that designation before.